Mortgage insurance provider cancelled insurance without notice, Bank does not refund even though I had no coverage
I pay my insurance monthly with my mortgage payment. On the anniversary date my policy did not renew because they stopped offering coverage in my state. I received no notice until 5 months later when my bank contacted me. I got a policy through a local agent who I instructed to send the invoice to my bank.
Several days ago my bank contacted me saying I have not had insurance all year. The agent neglected to follow through with the policy. I was told by the bank that I would be getting a large check. I had paid insurance all year. I immediately got a policy and had the invoice sent to my bank yesterday.
Summary:

Year 1 I paid insurance monthly to bank. Annual premium $1700.
Year 2 I had no insurance but paid the same premium to the bank monthly.
Year 3 I just bought a policy that is $1200 per year.

The bank will not issue a refund saying they need all of the money I paid in to pay this policy. Does the bank collect the premium all year then use it to pay the next years premium?
I assume I paid the first year of insurance out of loan proceeds. If so, the premiums I paid over the first 12 months should all be in the account because I had no insurance the 2nd year. Plus I paid premiums every month the 2nd year, which is in the escrow account. I believe I am owed 1 year of premiums from my bank.

Are you getting escrow statements? Why are you using escrow at all?

The settlement documents should specify how much went to the insurance company immediately and how much of the monthly payment was being used to set aside for to pay for the next time an insurance premium is due.
If this was related to the purchase of a house the policy would have started around the same date as the settlement date, and the amount sent to them as a part of the settlement would have matched the annual premium. If this was a refinance the next premium could have been been due at any time, so money might not have been sent to the insurance company with the settlement funds.

On the anniversary date my policy did not renew because they stopped
offering coverage in my state.i received no notice until 5 months
later when my bank contacted me. I got a policy through a local agent
who I instructed to send the invoice to my bank.
Several days ago my bank contacted me saying I have not had insurance
all year. The agent neglected to follow through with the policy. I was
told by the bank that I would be getting a large check.

The company handling your mortgage payment should have been very concerned about the lack of insurance. Without insurance the people who invested in your mortgage now had their investment at risk. They should have asked for proof of insurance. When the due date for the previous policy passed without seeing a bill they should have contacted you.
You also should have followed up. The insurance company should have either sent you a bill or sent it to the escrow company. The insurance company should have sent you a notice when it wasn't paid.
The reason why you may be getting a big check is that the escrow company collected for 12 months enough money to pay your insurance bill, and this continued until it was time to do the annual recalculation of your escrow.

I immediately got a policy and had the invoice sent to my bank
yesterday.
Summary: year 1 I paid insurance monthly to bank. Annual premium
$1700. Year 2 I had no insurance but paid the same premium to the bank
monthly. For year 3 I just bought a policy that is $1200 per year. The
bank will not issue a refund saying they need all of the money I paid
in to pay this policy.

The escrow company normally only recalculates once a year. If the amount of excess funds in the account is small they will just reduce the monthly amount by an even smaller amount to slowly bring it back to the allowable range. If the overage is large, they may have to refund enough to bring your balance back to normal.

Does the bank collect the premium all year then use it to pay the next
years premium?

Yes. This is how an escrow account works.

If so, the premiums I paid over the first 12 months should all be in
the account because I had no insurance the 2nd year. Plus I paid
premiums every month the 2nd year, which is in the escrow account. I
believe I am owed 1 year of premiums from my bank.

You have to review the monthly transactions connected to your escrow account. Also review the statement where they recalculated your monthly escrow payments. You might have to log into your account to see the transactions. What you have stated is approximately correct, but the statements should give you the data you need.
